# Passing multiple list of data in a Web API endpoint

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have web api endpoint

```
[HttpPut]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Rights(
       [FromBody] IEnumerable<Rights> rights,
       [FromBody] IEnumerable<Permissions> permissions)
```

Any idea how can I pass these two array parameters in the body of the request. My code is something like this

```
public static async Task Request(this RequestData requestData, Context context)
        {
            var url = requestData.GetAbsoluteUrl();

            byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Serialize(requestData.Body, requestData.Body.GetType()));

            using (var client = new CustomWebClient(context, body))
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                await client.UploadAsync(url, requestData.Method.ToString(), body);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RequestBody
{
 public IEnumerable<Rights> rights
 public IEnumerable<Permissions> permissions
}
```

send this class object as `RequestData`